# Inflection point problem

Tags: calculus

I would like to know how to solve the following problem: The slope of the tangent line of the equation: $$y=ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx$$ is equal to 4 at the point of inflection (1,5). Find the values of a,b and c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ then the information you have gives you three equations:
$$f(1)=5\text{, because this is a point on the graph of $f$},$$
$$f'(1)=4\text{, because this is the slope of the tangent,}$$
$$f''(1)=0\text{ because this is necessary for $(1,5)$ to be a point of inflection}.$$
This leads you to a system of three linear equations with three variables. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh thank you. I wasn't very sure of what to do with the inflection point information so I was getting 2 equations for 3 unknowns. Thank you alot for you answer, I can take it from here!

Comment: You're welcome! A positive sign of $f''$ means left curvature ( convex), a negative sign right curvature ( concave), at a point of inflection $(x,f(x))$ there must hold $f''(x)=0$